# Should you allow self transfers?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm new to this and I have a question regarding the following case:

```
   function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _amount
 ) internal returns(bool) {
       // Do not allow transfer to 0x0 or the token contract itself
      require((_to != 0) && (_to != address(this)));
 }
```

Should you also check for _from != _to? To avoid self transfers.
Is that a security risk?

Comment: how can i make transfer without receiving my OTP

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35834)

Answer (score 1):

IMO: This is not a security risk, its just a foolishness from the senders side. If sender transfers himself anything, it would be possible. The only thing I see wrong here is that this would be wastage of gas and senders ether in transaction.

### Need for checking

Zero address check is there so that the transfer is not made accidentally to zero address, in which case things will be lost forever. While in this case, there is no chance of things getting lost.